# The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found in WSO2 EI 6.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I Created a DSS and exposed as a REST resource and it's working fine in Management Console try this service option, but while trying from the postman I get the following **The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found** error please help me to sort this out.

[Postman Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0T9B.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting a SOAPAction or Action header which is required. You can determine that header either based on the WSDL of the DSS, or from the example call that you make with Try This Service from the management console.

Answer (score 0):

In default configuration, the DSS REST endpoint is exposed with address like:

```
http://{EI_ADDRESS}/services/{YOUR_DSS_SERVICE_NAME}.HTTPEndpoint/{REST_RESOURCE_PATH}
```

So your url doesn't point to REST resource.
Also sending data in POST to that DSS REST endpoint should be "wraped" in value object like:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "id": "10"
  }
}
```